# How can I get the given result but with \documentclass{article} instead of \documentclass{report}?

Tags: document-classes, appendices, article, report, appendix

Using this code with `\documentclass{report}`

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{appendix}


\begin{document}
    
    \appendix
    \chapter{title of this section }
    \label{sect:app}
    \renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}
    Let us consider
    \begin{equation}
        f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c
    \end{equation}
    
    then, in Appendix~\ref{sect:app}, we have ...
\end{document}
```

I get this result

[image]

This code does not work with the `\documentclass{article}`, I want to get the same result but with `\documentclass{article}`, how can I do this?

I appreciate any comments in advance.

Comment: you are using `\chapter` more or less the only difference between `report` and `article` is that `report` defines `\chapter` (the two classes come from the same source file) so anything that adds `\chaper` to `article` is equivalent to "use `report` instead"

Comment: if you want an appendix in article, use `\section` not `\chapter`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Then, it does not show the word "Appendix", it only gives "A".

Comment: shrug, that is more fitting for the article class (which still has very flamboyant headings by most standards) It does not write **Chapter 2** in front of the non-appendix sections either.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Moreover, it does not provide numbering in this way, A.1 .

Comment: yes it does: the first `\subsection` would be A.1  just as in the rest of `article` `\section` is the top level, `\subsection` the next.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I meant equation numbering, not sections.

Comment: well naturally `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}` should be `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}`  in article as there are no chapters. (although that would be the default if you have defined equations to be numbered per-section)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks.